# Apple In App purchase with sandBox gets an error as “Your account has been disabled in the App Store and iTunes”

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, itunes, testflight

An iOS App has given for testing in TestFlight for testing In-App purchase
It used to test using the sandBox account, but now it's not working with sandBox and gets an error as “Your account has been disabled in the App Store and iTunes”.

Rechecked the product creation and checked the same - it's not worked.
Then created a new sandbox account and tried the same - its not worked, showed the same error.

Checked the issues in the web and from the related answers, tried to remove the account details from **Settings** --> **iTunes & App Store** - its not worked, showed the same error.

Answer (score 1):

TestFlight users don't require a sandbox account, but they will test against an automatically created sandbox account.

This means it's no longer necessary to create test accounts in iTunes Connect.
Your TestFlight user is a legitimate App Store user, but doing in-app purchases made with beta builds are free within the context of the beta version.

More details available in the following section [Testing in-app purchases with TestFlight](https://help.testlio.com/en/articles/464611-testing-in-app-purchases-on-ios#:%7E:text=Testing%20in%2Dapp%20purchases%20with,test%20accounts%20in%20iTunes%20Connect.) by Marko Kruustük.